# formidablepro2pdf checkbox / radio not working

Tags: wordpress, pdftk, formidable

I am using formidablepdfpro in my website and all the pdf mapping are working fine but out of these a radio button with the following label:

- Neuanmeldung
- Übernahme Übernahme Neuanmeldung mit
- Rufnummernportierung
- Vertragsverlängerung

Not working properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.formidablepro2pdf.com/support/subject/check-boxes-are-not-working/

You can try this.
Regarding Radio Buttons, you MUST name all PDF options the same, and change the PDF Radio Button EXPORT VALUE of each option to match (use copy/paste) each value from the Formidable Form radio button field options. (Again, if the Formidable checkbox value is too long or contains special characters, then use Formidable’s “Separate Values” function)

Comment: @AwsmeSandy, Bro if it works you then please mark it as **the answer** so others can follow it.